# Web Job - I can´t create and delete, changed the appearance of the web job screen

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs-triggered

I can´t delete a web job. I can´t create a new web job too.
When I try to delete a web job it fails.
When I create a web job it says it will be updates soon but it doesn't update and it doesn't create.
Changed the appearance of the web job screen as well.

I don't know if a new test view, but it doesn't work.

I think it's some new test view not working.

Comment: It worked fine a week ago.

Comment: How you are creating a WebJob?Are you trying to do it in Azure Portal ?

Comment: Please share more details about the WebJob.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When I create the webjob with another account it works, but when I create it with the account I created before and it worked, it doesn't work anymore.
Changed the screen view of the account that stopped working, it is different from the other account that works.
I create a web job in Portal.